# Apple's Gallery Overlay Lightbox

Tags: javascript, popup, lightbox, modalpopups

I'm looking for something very, very close in functionality to the lightbox on
[Apple's MacBook Pro website](http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/overlays/redesigned.html#redesigned) (the lightbox will open automatically).

I really need the thumbnail slider and the text-area. The layout can be different, as I have the skills to remodel it if need be, I just don't have the time to build it from scratch.

No preference of dependent libraries.

Comment: Who-ever voted this down, would you care to explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up combining [JCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/index.php) with [Galleria](http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/) and using [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) to pull it altogether - took longer than I had available, but the client will be happy I hope ...

Comment: For anyone interesting in seeing the final result:
http://phalacee.com/dev/lightboxen/

Answer (score 1):

If you use a standard lightbox, you could probably incorporate this control into it:

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/slider-gallery.html

or maybe you're looking for something more like this:

http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/index.php

Basically what you want is a lightbox with an embedded carousel control

Comment: yeah, highslide has that already, but I'm also after the large text content area too

Comment: the content areas will just be standard divs that get updated via ajax when the click even of the objects in the slider are fired

Comment: Yeah, I know, but as I said in my OP, I don't have the time (that is, the boss won't allocate me work hours) to spend building a solution from scratch ...